# How do I click a link and make the game pop up in a certain area on my page without showing till clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to figure out how to make a link on my page access a game in a certain spot on the same page. I have multipal games that are embeded>. So I have multipal links on the same page.
So Basically after I click one of the links, it will do a pop up in any area next to the link and they can play it. If someone can help me out I will give you much credit needed.
I'm using antenna web design and I'm not sure if I need to call functions so I can put the code in a certain area. Thank You For Your Time If You Help.

Comment: Please work out the difference between Java & JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  in the same page means use

```
     <iframe></iframe>
```

otherwise just make a link. it will open same window or use target="_blank" it will open for a tab

Comment: I Didnt Want It To Open In New Tab.. I Wanted It To Do A Pop Up.. But Pop Ups Are In A New Window Still.. I Wanted It To Be In The Same Page Imprinted In The Page.. But I Got It Figured Out With This Antenna Design.. Its amazing Drag And Drop Links It Together Amazing.. Thank You Tho For Your Help..

Answer (score 0):

try to send the video Id in link and filter the video id from querystring on click event

Comment: I Wanted To Know The Coding For It.. But I Was Playing Around And I Created A Text Field And Drug The HTML File To The Text And It Linked It.. It Works Great.. I Can Just Place The File Where I Want On The Screen And It Will Show Up There When I Click The Link LOL.. But I Would However Like The Code Ur Talking About If Poossible.. Im Just Learning But Anything Helps.. Thank You..